# % probability of 1-3 on 7 consecutive dice throws

Tags: probability

What is the percent chance of landing 1-3 on 7 dice tosses in a row?

I rolled seven dice I believe at the same time and they all landed on one to three instead of four to six.

My attempt at this came out as a 4% chance I treated the dice rolls kind of like coin tosses because it seemed to me the chances of each one were 50/50 so I took 10 and divided it by two seven times since each dice roll was a 50% chance out of 100% I got 0.04 then I turned it to a percentage by multiplying it by 100 because I thought it would come to be the % out of 100% if multiplied by 100.

I believe my technique was wrong though and came to the incorrect answer as I am only 24 and barely understand math.

Also for the record it was seven dice not one.

After hearing one comment I tried another strategy since each dice toss was a 50% chance and I rolled 7 of them I took 7 and divided it by 50 arriving at 0.14%

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! Since this is a site that encourages and helps with *learning*, it is best if you show your own ideas and efforts in solving the question. Can you edit your question to add your thoughts and ideas about it? Don't worry if it's wrong - that's what we're here for.

Comment: Also, don't get discouraged by the downvote. I downvoted the question and voted to close it because at the moment, it is not up to site standards (you have shown no work you did on your own). If you edit your question so that you show what you tried and how far you got, I will not only remove the downvote, I will add an upvote. Even if the question is closed, you can still edit it, and we will vote to reopen it.

Comment: What is the probability of the first toss being 1-3 ? How about the second? How about third?

Comment: Added my attempt at solving the problem.

Comment: You are correct that the chance of rolling $1-3$ each time is $50$%; why did you take $10$ and divide it by $2$ seven times?  if you took $100$% and divided it by $2$ seven times, then you would get the correct answer

Comment: The probability is $\frac12$.  If you multiply $\frac12$ by itself $7$ times you get the correct answer of $0.0078125$.

Answer (score 1):

For independent events, $A$ and $B$, the probability of both occurring, notated as $Pr(A\cap B)$ will equal $Pr(A)\times Pr(B)$.  (*Please be aware that this works only for independent events*).

The outcomes of each individual die are independent of one another and so the probability that you roll a low number on the first *and* the second *and* the third, and so on, will be the probability that you roll a low number on the first *times* the probability that you roll a low number on the second *times* etc...

$Pr(\text{1-3 on all seven dice}) = \frac{1}{2}\times\frac{1}{2}\times\cdots\times\frac{1}{2}=\frac{1}{2^7}$

Suggested further reading: [Binomial Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution)